# Get doc library ID from trigger

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, power-automate, flow, power-platform

I want to place the GUID for the library specified in an automated flow trigger into a variable. This variable will then be passed to a child flow.

The trigger is "when a file is created or modified (properties only)".

When I look at the output of the trigger, I do not see the library listed anywhere.

This child flow will be called by at least 30 library-specific parent flows, so I would prefer not to have to manually pull the library GUID for each parent flow.

Where can I find the GUID of the library, based on the trigger?

Comment: Do you need GUID only or you will be fine if you can get the library "name"? How you are using GUID in child flow?

Comment: My understanding is that I must have the library GUID to specify the library in an action like "Update file properties".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use flow like this:

[image]

**Expressions used**:

**Compose action**:

```
first(split(triggerOutputs()?['body/{Path}'],'/'))
```

**Compose 2 action**:

```
body('Send_an_HTTP_request_to_SharePoint')['d']['results'][0]['Id']
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you - I answered your top level question above. Do I need the GUID to specify the library in an action like "Update file properties"?

Comment: I think using either one should work for you. Try using GUID for safer side in case library display name and URL name is different.

Comment: In trying this, I'm getting an empty array from the Send an HTTP request to SharePoint action. I've triple-checked that I've entered everything in the action correctly. Suggestions?

Comment: Is it working now or you are still facing this issue? Make sure you have enclosed library name in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The only action I can see is [Get lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#get-lists), which will return the lists from the site, this may return what you need.

Alternatively, you could use the SharePoint REST API to return the list details via the [Send an HTTP request to SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#send-an-http-request-to-sharepoint).